# How to add secondary exposed form elements using "Better exposed module" in views

Tags: views

[image: BEF settings in view edit section]

[image: clicking on this advanced will show another options or filters(I think it is similar to advanced search)]

I just want to know how to add elements like another exposed filter in this advanced tabs.Currently it is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Below the field which will be secondary open **MORE OPTIONS** and check **This is a secondary option** check box and save.

After that, it will display in Advanced